# Self-Terminating AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, terminate

Is there a way that Amazon Web Services EC2 instances can be self terminating?  Does Amazon have anything that allows an instance to terminate itself ("Hara-Kiri") after running for more than say an hour?  I could change the scripts on the running instance to do this itself, but that might fail and I don't want to edit the image, so I would like Amazon to kill the instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, I need an emergency shutoff switch if the instance lasts more than X amount of hours.  My use case is that I use Amazon's EC2 to quickly spin an instance, run some process on Ubuntu (that takes about 5 minutes) and then shut itself down.  This is being controlled by a windows desktop app.  Most of the time it works like a charm, however, sometimes a user closes their laptop and goes on vacation for a week and guess what, I have AWS charges for a 168 hours that I didn't need.
If anyone wants more details, I can tell you all about it.
Steve

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To have an instance terminate itself do both of these steps:

1. Start the instance with `--instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate` or the equivalent on the AWS console or API call.
2. Run `shutdown -h now` as root.  On Ubuntu, you could set this up to happen in 55 minutes using:

   ```
   echo "sudo halt" | at now + 55 minutes
   ```

I wrote an article a while back on other options to accomplish this same "terminate in an hour" goal:

> Automatic Termination of Temporary Instances on Amazon EC2
>   http://alestic.com/2010/09/ec2-instance-termination

The article was originally written before `instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior` was available, but you'll find updates and other gems in the comments.

Comment: Eric, thank you, but I don't see where I can do #1 on the AWS console.  I see a "Shutdown Behavior" setting in "Request Instances Wizard", but the only options are "Terminate" and "Stop".  This doesn't actually schedule the instance to stop in an hour.  I'm going to check in the AWS .NET API that I am using to launch the instance to see if I can do something like that.

Comment: You set "shutdown behavior" to "terminate" and then execute "halt" or "shutdown -h now" on the instance when you want it to terminate.  Schedule in advance using "at".  (1) and (2) are required steps in a single process, not alternative approaches.

Comment: Any reason for doing "shutdown -h now" as opposed to "shutdown -P now" ?

Comment: @EricHammond The reason I ask is that my instances fail to shutdown about 5% of the time (they get stuck into a wedged state where they are running but won't terminate and can't be ssh'd into). Was just wondering if that might be the cause.

Comment: @DustinBoswell it can be that you are using "halt" or "shutdown -h" which isn't the same as poweroff, depending on the system settings. Try "sudo poweroff" (or "sudo shutdown -P now", but I like "poweroff" for it's verbosity) instead.

Answer (score 26):

You can do this

```
ec2-terminate-instances $(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
```

The ec2 will get its current instance id and terminate itself.

Comment: I like this method... but it requires that you have credentials set up on the instance to run terminate-instances. That won't always be the case, and you'll get a "Client.UnauthorizedOperation" error.

Comment: You can set up an instance profile, which would remove the need for setting up credentials.

Comment: @RaveTheTadpole if you want an instance to terminate itself, it needs permission to terminate itself. Its an implicit condition.

Answer (score 14):

Hopefully this will work

```
instanceId=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/)
region=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep region | awk '{print $3}' | sed  's/"//g'|sed 's/,//g')

/usr/bin/aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $instanceId --region $region
```

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: Thanks! I modified it slightly, I don't know if you use jq, but figured I'd share either way. region=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .region)

Answer (score 8):

Here is my script for ***Self-Terminating***

```
$ EC2_INSTANCE_ID="`wget -q -O - http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id || die \"wget instance-id has failed: $?\"`"
$ echo "ec2-terminate-instances $EC2_INSTANCE_ID" | at now + 55 min || die 'cannot obtain instance-id'
```

If you want to assign it as ***Self-Stopping*** on *Self-Terminating*, you can do it one time only.

In your *[EC2 Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#Instances:sort=instanceId)* go to *Instance Settings*, change *Shutdown Behavior*  to *Stop*.
Configure */etc/cloud/cloud.cfg*, you may refer to *[how to run a boot script using cloud-init](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476752/4058484)*.
Follow answer from [Eric Hammond](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455027/4058484), put the command in a file and locate it in [*scripts-per-boot*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455027/4058484) path:

```
$ echo '#!/bin/sh' > per-boot.sh
$ echo 'echo "halt" | at now + 55 min' >> per-boot.sh
$ echo 'echo per-boot: `date` >> /tmp/per-boot.txt' >> per-boot.sh
$ chmod +x per-boot.sh
$ sudo chown -R root per-boot.sh
$ sudo mv -viu per-boot.sh /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot
```

[Reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637856/4058484) your instance, check if the script is executed:

```
$ cat /tmp/per-boot.txt 
per-boot: Mon Jul 4 15:35:42 UTC 2016
```

If so, just in case you forgot to stop your instance, it will assure you that the instance will do itself termination as stopping when it has run for 55 minutes or whatever time you set in the script.

```
Broadcast message from root@ip-10-0-0-32
        (unknown) at 16:30 ...

The system is going down for halt NOW!
```

PS: For everyone want to use the *Self-Stopping*, one thing you should note that not all EC2 types are self recovery on restarting. I recommend to use [*EC2-VPC/EBS*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235022/4058484) with *[On/Off Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408077/4058484)*.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, where I had web applications firing up EC2 instances. I could not trust the web application to stop/terminate the instances, so I created a script to run in a separate process, called the "feeder". The feeder owns the responsibility of stopping/terminating the instance. The web application must periodically request that the feeder "feed" the instance. If an instance "starves" (is not fed within a timeout period), the feeder will stop/terminate it. Two feeders can be run simultaneously on different machines to protect against issues with one feeder process. In other words, the instance runs on a pressure switch. When pressure is released, the instance is stopped/terminated. This also allows me to share an instance among multiple users.

To the original question, the feeder, which could be running in the EC2 instance itself, eliminates the need to know a priori how long the task will be running, but it places a burden on the application to provide periodic feedings. If the laptop is closed, the instance will go down.

The feeder lives here: https://github.com/alessandrocomodi/fpga-webserver and has a permissive open-source license.